# script does not print variable value consistently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python 3 script that scans a folder for a certain file type, then gets the filename with extension and without extension.

For some reason, it is not printing out the filename without the extension.

Here is the script:

```
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".rew"):
        astroFileName = file
        astroFileTitle = print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        print(astroFileName)
        print(astroFileTitle)

        data = dict(
            Astro_Name=file,
            Astro_Title=astroFileTitle,

        commands = """\
            max_copy cp {Astro_Name} {Astro_Title}
            reginto_f /r /w {Astro_Title}
        """

        for command in commands.splitlines():
            command = command.format(**data) 
            print(command)
```

So for example, if the file name is 'modern_star_chart.rew', it prints out:

```
modern_star_chart.rew
modern_star_chart
modern_star_chart.rew None
None
```

As you can see, it will print out astroFileTitle once, but not the second time, it just prints None.

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do we have all the code? For the data dictionary, I do not see the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function doesn't returns any value that is it returns `None`.

Replace:

```
    astroFileTitle = print(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
```

With:

```
    astroFileTitle = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
```